# Spring Boot BindingResult doesn't show any error message

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Here below the snapshot of my code, it doesn't show any error message to into the controller while I am inputting incorrect Values

While executing this code, it can be accessed by all of the inputted data, Like username as null or one character, email is not showing the proper types of email.

**How can I solve my issue for data validation?**

**Controller class**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class UserRegistrationController {

    @GetMapping
    public String showRegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute("userRegistrationDto")UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto) {
        return "registration";
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public String registerUserAccount(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userRegistrationDto")  UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        System.out.println(userRegistrationDto);
        model.addAttribute("data", userRegistrationDto);
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println("error found");
            return "registration";
        }
```

**UserRegistraionDto Class**

```
public class UserRegistrationDto {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @Size(min = 3, max = 15)
    private String username;
    @Email(message = "Email is not Valid")
    private String email;
    @Size(min = 9, max = 11, message = "phone number must be 11 digit")
    private String phone;
    private String address;
    private String password;

    public UserRegistrationDto(String name, String username, String email, String phone, String address, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**registration.html page**

```
<div class="container regPage">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <!-- success message -->
            <div th:if="${param.success}">
                <div class="alert alert-info">You've successfully registered
                    to our awesome app!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center sign">
                <h1>Registration Form</h1>
            </div>
            <form th:action="@{/registration}" method="post" th:object="${userRegistrationDto}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label"  for="name"> Name </label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"
                           required autofocus="autofocus"/>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="username"> User Name </label> <input
                        id="username"  name="username" class="form-control" th:field="*{username}"
                        required autofocus="autofocus"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="email"> Email </label> <input
                        id="email" name="email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}" required
                        autofocus="autofocus"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="phone"> Phone </label> <input
                        id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" th:field="*{phone}"
                        required autofocus="autofocus"/>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="address"> Address </label> <input
                        id="address" name="address" class="form-control" th:field="*{address}"
                        required autofocus="autofocus"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="password"> Password </label> <input
                        id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password"
                        th:field="*{password}" required autofocus="autofocus"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="text-center">
                <span>Already registered? <a href="/" th:href="@{/login}"> Login here</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**pom.xml file**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Add `@ModelAttribute` next to `@Valid` and remove the model and adding to the model from your method. You are basically overwriting things.

Comment: I have tried with this, but this also shows the same @M.Deinum

Comment: Yeah, I have added the ```@EnableWebMvc``` in-app config file.  @Thomas

Comment: Put `@Validated` on top of `UserRegistrationController`...

Comment: The "Model model" may be the problem - try to remove it. Spring Boot is relying on some kind of parameter order.

Comment: I have also tried to add  ```@Validated```  and remove the ```Model model```  from the controller but it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring boot then instead of hibernate validator and validation API you can use

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```